# "Do without Loop" error

Tags: excel, vba

This subroutine was working well but now I'm getting a "Loop without Do" error:

```
Sub Upload_earned_pto()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim UID, PW, s1, s3, s5, s7 As String
Dim s4, s6 As Date
Dim s2 As Double


UID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
PW = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")


With Sheets("Monthly Adjustments")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=" & PW & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & UID & ";Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Data Source=TESTSRV;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=MPL-DEV1;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 8

    'Loop until empty cell in batch_skey
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        If Rows(iRowNo).Hidden = True Then
            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        ElseIf Rows(iRowNo).Hidden <> True Then

        s1 = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        s2 = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        s3 = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
        s4 = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
        s5 = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
        s6 = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)
        s7 = .Cells(iRowNo, 7)

'Generate and execute sql statement to export the excel rows to SQL Server table
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.pto_transactions values ('" & s1 & "', '" & s3 & "'

, '" & s6 & "', '" & s2 & "', '" & s4 & "', '" & s5 & "', '" & s7 & "')"
        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "PTO Transactions Successfully Sent."

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End With
```

Comment: You are missing an `end if`

Comment: I am idiot! Missed my End If!

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks man! literally just noticed it and posted my comment as well.

Comment: @ScottCraner or anybody - do you know why Excel can't instead tell us that "No End If" instead of the more cryptic "Do without Loop" error.  I've always wondered why it can't tell us there's no close to an `If` statement.   "Do without Loop" is misleading, because we have a `Do` and `Loop`!...although I suspect an answer to this is bigger than any comment can be :P

Comment: @BruceWayne I believe it throws the error of the outside wrapper.  If it was an if statement with a loop on the inside and the loop was missing the loop, next wend it would throw the if without end if.  As to why, that I do not know.

Comment: Well somebody answer it, or it will keep showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the End If. Thanks to @ScottCraner for pointing it out.